# $('parent > child > childOfChild > ...').css('background-color','red)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="galao">
   <div class="informacoesGalao invisible">
      <div class="tabelaInformacoes infoGalao" style="float:right; text-align:right">
         <p class="nomeGalao">Produto A</p>
         <p class="invisible volumeTotalGalao">1000</p>
         <p class="invisible volumeAtualGalao">800</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="desenhoGalao">
      <div class="bordasGalao">
         <div class="conteudoGalao"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

`.conteudoGalao { background-color: blue }`

I'm trying to select the `<div class="galao">` and change the background color of the child `<div class="conteudoGalao">`.

When the user clicks into the `<div class="galao">` this div turns into `<div id="selectedGalao" class="galao">`.

I've already tried `$('#selectedGalao > conteudoGalao').css('background-color','red')` but it doesn't even return a error or anything. Any idea of how I can make this work? Is there a specific jquery for this kind of "grandson div"?

Comment: `conteudoGalao` in a selector means the _element_ `conteudoGalao`, you mean the _class_, so use `.conteudoGalao`.

Answer (score 1):

The '>' css selector is for direct children. Since conteudoGalao is a grandchild it will not work. Simply use `$('#selectedGalao .conteudoGalao').css('background-color','red')` instead unless that's not specific enough, in which case I'll need more info as to why. IF that's how your markup will always work, and you do want to be extremely explicit in your selector, `$('#selectedGalao > .desenhoGalao > .bordasGalao > .conteudoGalao').css('background-color','red')`. Lastly, as CalvT said, you are also missing a period in front of 'conteudoGalao' to label it as a class.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your jQuery. Try the following:

```
$('#selectedGalao .conteudoGalao').css('background-color','red')
```

You weren't specifying that `conteudoGalao` was a class, so do this by adding the `.` As the `.` was missing, jQuery was looking for an element called `conteudoGalao`

The `>` is for direct children, and `conteudoGalao` is not.